# Grails using grails var in GSP Site inside javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, grails, gsp

I have a question using grails variable values in javascript code in a GSP file.

For Example: I have a session value **session.getAttribute("selectedValue")** and I want to use this value inside javascript code part.

My solution is now (inside a GSP):

```
<%
    def js = new String("<script type=\"text/javascript\">")
    js += "var jsSelectedValue = " + session.getAttribute("selectedValue") + ";"
    js += "</script>"
    out << js
%>
```

and then I have javascript block inside my GSP with jQuery Stuff and so on, there I need this value.

Is there another way to have grails variables accessible inside pure javascript code?

And second question, the exactly other way around. I select for example in a dropdown box and click "save" and then i want to store the value $("#select-box").val() inside a session variable from JS-part.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Cheers,

Marco

Comment: You're not really referencing any grails variables in the code above. What you're actually doing is using generating javascript code from a template. This template can access the session because it is processed on the server side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why do not use the javascript GSP-tag? A solution can look like this:

```
<g:javascript>
    var jsSelectedValue = "${session.selectedValue}"; 
</g:javascript>
```

Comment: Not sure if anyone else will get stuck in the same way I did, but make sure that the var declaration is in a separate tag than any script with a source parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your first problem might be as follows:

**UPDATE:** Modifications according to @Medrod's solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsSelectedValue = "${session.selectedValue}";
</script>
```

And for second question:
Send selected value to server and set session variable.

Comment: Thanks Medrod and Zedwal!

For the answer of the second question, if I send everything to the server (e.g. JSON POST) every script kiddie can prepare some local form values and prepared ajax post and manipulte... right?!